# Undo convertToCapped to a collection

Tags: mongodb, nosql

In MongoDB you can convert a collection into a capped collection with the command `convertToCapped`, but is there a way to revert this change so a capped collection goes back to normal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's seems there is only one way to convert from capped collection to normal - just simple copy objects to normal collection and remove original capped collection.

```
db.createCollection("norm_coll");
var cur = db.cap_col.find()
while (cur.hasNext()) {obj = cur.next(); db.norm_coll.insert(obj);}
```

Comment: I haven't found any command to just revert the conversion, so it must be true that the only option is to sump all elements into a new collection, which is a shame. I hope they work that out.

Answer (score 0):

same as above without using script.

```
    db.collection.copyTo("collection_temp")
    db.collection.drop()
    db.collection_temp.renameCollection("collection")
```

Comment: This can be done only for mongo below 4.0
Since it copyto (eval) is deprecated in 4.2

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a way! I'm not sure if this is bullet-proof, but I tried:

```
db.num_coll.convertToCapped(new_size)
```

and since then it is working.

Comment: This just changes the capacity of the capped collection, it doesn't "uncap" the collection.