# Mongo and capped collections

Tags: mongodb, collections

I'm using Mongo (2.6.7) and I need to update my existing Capped Collection, to a *'regular'* collection that it is **not capped**.

Is there any way, using the mongo command shell, to achieve this? If is possible, I don't want to drop and recreate the collection (as it's a production system).

I see there is a `convertToCapped` function but is there something that will work the other way?

Comment: This should help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3971689/undo-converttocapped-to-a-collection

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to do it without dropping it. 
what you can do is rename the existing capped collection. And create a new collection which is normal with the old collection's name.

You can use the link in the comment.

Answer (score -1):

```
db.runCommand({"convertToCapped":"posts",size:10000})
```

change "posts" to capped collections